# JS: Promise resolver is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to run this jestJS unit-test, but I do get `TypeError: Promise resolver undefined is not a function`. What am I doing wrong?

```
it('_onSubmit() should throw error if data is missing', (done) => {
  const createUserMutation = () => new Promise()
  const wrapper = shallow(<CreateAccount createUserMutation={createUserMutation} />)
  wrapper.update().find(Form).simulate('submit', {
    preventDefault: () => {}
  })
  createUserMutation.resolve().then(() => {
    expect(console.error).toHaveBeenCalled()
    done()
  })
})
```

Comment: The Promise constructor expects a function. And promise instances don’t have a `resolve` method.

Comment: I'm having an extremely hard time trying to figure out how this test is supposed to work. Can you walk us through the thought process that led to this code and what you're trying to use the promise for?

Comment: Why are you using promises here at all? What part of the code is asynchronous?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`new Promise()` is trying to create a promise without an executor function*. The correct usage is to pass in a function that accepts up to two parameters (`resolve` and `reject`), e.g.:

```
var p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // ...code that does something, ultimately calls either resolve or reject
});
```

More on MDN:

- [The `Promise` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [Using Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Later, you appear to be trying to call `resolve` on the promise instance. You can't do that either (unless you're not using standard promises). You resolve a promise using the `resolve` function passed into the executor. (I tried to modify your code for you, but too much context info is required.)

---

* I'm surprised to see V8's error message say "resolver function" but I've verified it does. [The spec](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-promise-executor) calls it an executor, and I would have thought a "resolver functioN" would be the function the `Promise` constructor passes as the first argument to it...

Comment: But I don't understand how get the `resolve().then()` into the Promise...

Comment: @user3142695: I'm afraid I can't follow your code. Often, all of the action takes place *inside* the promise executor, but in your case that's wrapped in an arrow function; without knowing more about your project I'm afraid I can't really explain how to update that code. See the linked articles (I've added a second one) for more information about how to use promises in general, though.

Answer (score 4):

If all you want to do is create a resolved promise, then use `Promise.resolve()`, which returns a new, already resolved promise.

`new Promise()` is for converting non-promise (usually asynchronous) code to promises, but it doesn't look like you need that here. If you were going to use it, you would have to pass a function into it (as Felix Kling and TJ Crowder have already noted).

Some more points:

- You are defining `createUserMutation` as a function, so a few lines later when you use it, you would need to *call* it using `()`. Or you could choose to have it not be a function since it seems all you're trying to do here is produce a promise.
- Also, as Felix Kling has pointed out, promises don't have a `resolve()` method. You can just call `.then()` on the promise produced by `Promise.resolve()`.

Comment: FWIW, re your first bullet point, I suspect it's correct as-is: She/He's passing the function, not its result, as a prop to <CreateAccount> (probably so it can call it when mutating the user). (But obviously we'd need more context to be sure either way.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case using types like TypeScript was an issue.

```
const a = new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {})
```

This wasn't acceptable in JavaScript and it spits the error "Promise resolver is not a function". However, when I deleted the type it works fine.

```
const a = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {})
```